# running java program written in Eclipse IDE that uses anltr3 grammars via command line

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, antlr

I've written a class that utilizes antlr grammars in the Eclipse IDE that i'm having trouble running outside Eclipse.

Here is my directory:
[image: ls]

I run: `antlr3 *\.g`

[image: antlr3 *.g then ls]

Next I run `javac -cp /home/linux/BB_Grammar/antlr-3.3-complete.jar:. *\.java`
[image: javac -cp /home/linux/BB_Grammar/antlr-3.3-complete.jar:. *.java then ls]

OK, so BB_Test.java contains my main method, so I'm going to try to run BB_Test next.
I'm going to bring a test file into the directory `test.s`.

`java BB_Test test.s`
[image: java BB_Test test.s]

I have a feeling that this error is due to the program being written in the Eclipse IDE, but I really am not sure. Appreciate any help... this is kind of frustrating me.

update: I thought that perhaps the error was due to various package statements contained in the files, so I went ahead and deleted all of them and tried running the final statement again (`java BB_Test test.s`). This is output:

[image: tried to fix error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all related to not specifying the classpath properly, and has nothing to do with source files being generated by either Eclipse, or from the command line.

If the following command worked for you:

```
javac -cp /home/linux/BB_Grammar/antlr-3.3-complete.jar:. *\.java
```

then you should be able to run `BB_Test` as follows:

```
java -cp /home/linux/BB_Grammar/antlr-3.3-complete.jar:. BB_Test test.s
```

If not, please post your source files (Java and ANTLR files!).